# Disable network access during Maven test runs

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to improve our unit tests by making sure our Jenkins builds fail if the tests try to make outbound network calls (indicating mocking was not done). I can't find a way to disable network connections in Java, JUnit, Maven, Surefire, Jenkins, or any other part of the process. Is there a way to do this? Preferably as something we can enable for new projects (so we don't make all of our old stuff unbuildable).

Comment: Do I correctly understand your unit tests are using mocking to prevent network accesses? Apart from that you could try to run your build within a docker container which can be controlled..but I think that would be hard thing to do...but the question is: Is the only reason to disable network access to find some tests which do not use mocking for networking?

Comment: There is little mocking done, I want to strongly encourage mocking by making tests that don't use mocks properly fail in the Jenkins build.

It's not just finding the tests, it's to prevent people from building tests in the future without proper mocking.

Comment: Hm...prevent people from using mocks? In general or just for particular tests? I'm not sure what the real problem is but https://www.archunit.org/ might be something to take a look at.. ?

Comment: I don't want to prevent people from using mocks; I want to prevent people from writing their tests *without* mocks and having unit tests call real services.

Comment: Prevent people from writing a test without mocks sounds strange cause sometimes it's easier without mocks .. And what do you mean by "having unit tests call real services" (My POV is: Services are usually already integration tests but that depends).

Comment: Would support to topic starter - most modern build systems support disabling network access for Unit test to enforce them being Unit. But apparently it seems maven is not modern enough